# Integrate $e^{-\frac{y^2}{2}}\left(\frac{1}{y^2}+1\right)$

Tags: calculus, integration

I'm trying to find $$\displaystyle  \int{e^{-\frac{y^2}{2}}} \left(\frac{1}{y^2}+1\right)dy$$
I tried using integration by parts and some substitutions, but nothing seem to work.

The answer is $\displaystyle  -\frac{{e^{-\frac{y^2}{2}}}}{y}$.

Please help, thank you.

Comment: Well for a start, you could derive the answer and see that it fits.

Comment: Galc127 I think that there should be a negative sign in the answer.

Comment: @SherlockHolmes, absolutely right, thanks for noticing.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You must use integration by parts.

First split the integrand into $$\int \frac{e^{\frac{-y^2}{2}}}{y^2}dy + \int e^{\frac{-y^2}{2}}dy$$

Using by parts on the first integral, $$\int \frac{e^{\frac{-y^2}{2}}}{y^2} dy=-\frac{e^{\frac{-y^2}{2}}}{y}-\int e^{\frac{-y^2}{2}}dy$$

This nicely cancels out with the second integral and yields the required result.

Comment: A great answer, thanks. BTW, you have a little mistake in the last line - it should be a (-) sign instead of (+) sign.

Comment: @Galc127 Thanks for noticing that but it appears someone has beaten me to editing it.